# Regex for a Phone number and Extension only

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've attempted multiple times to write a regex field validator for an asp.net intranet form web form. I've tried to tweek mine with no success. The current one i'm using and attempting to edit is

```
((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}
```

I need to be able to allow.

```
x1245
508-555-1212
5085551212
508 555 1212
508-555-1212 x1234
5085551212 x1243
508 555 1212 x1234
```

The only one i have covered is the second one on the list is the second one down.

Comment: Check out www.regexlib.com - there are sample regex's on there that may point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it.

```
(\d\d\d-?\s?\d\d\d-?\s?\d\d\d\d\s?)?(x\d\d\d\d)?
```

or shorter equivalent:

```
(\d{3}-?\s?\d{3}-?\s?\d{4}\s?)?(x\d{4})?
```

You want to match the full phone number, optionally with space/dash, and make that whole thing optional, then include extension, and make that optional too.

Comment: Note, this will also match an empty string.

Comment: Close.  You're missing a match for the optional space between the number and the extension.  I went with this `(\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}\s?)?\s?(x{1}\d{4})?

Comment: @MauriceReeves But that would match without the space separating number an extension, will also match the empty string and will also match a leading/trailing space if the extension or number is missing

Comment: Needs to be wrapped with `^` and `$` to match entire string, also if you put `(?<=.)$` on the end instead of just `$` it will prevent matching the zero length string

Comment: @MauriceReeves, the match for empty space is there, before the first closing paren.

Comment: I'm trying to add ?(\d{7}$)? to the end of expression so that it allows....... #######....right now my expression looks like this........(\d{3}-?\s?\d{3}-?\s?\d{4}\s?)?(x\d{4})?(\d{4}\s?)?(\d{3}-?\s?\d{4})?(\d{7}$)?....it allowing everything i need it to do minus just putting 7 numbers in a row which would seem to be the easiest of all things

Answer (score 4):

A pattern like this would match all your inputs:

```
\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}( x\d{4})?|x\d{4}
```

This will match either:

- three digits
- an optional space or hyphen
- three digits
- an optional space or hyphen
- four digits
- an optional group of:

  - a space, and a literal `x`
  - four digits

  —or—
- a space, and a literal `x`
- four digits

Depending on your precise needs, you may need to start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors to prohibit extra characters around your pattern (e.g. `"foo x1234 bar"`):

```
^\d{3}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}( x\d{4})?|x\d{4}$
```

**Update**

If you'd like to ensure that the digit two separators between the three phone number segments must be the same—e.g. `508-555 1212` would not be allowed—the easiest way would be something like this:

```
\d{3}([- ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}( x\d{4})?|x\d{4}
```

The `(...)` creates a capture group, and because it happens to be the first one in the pattern, it's referred to as group 1. The `\1` is a backreference, which will only match the exact string which was matched in group 1.

Comment: Only limitation is this will allow `508-555 1212` which the OP hasn't stated whether it's legal or not...

Comment: @BobVale That's true. I've provided an alternative pattern which should work in that case.

Comment: I defenitley prefer that the pattern be the same thru out the entry

Answer (score 2):

This one quite complicated but will match

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?<number>\d{3}(?<separator>([\s-]|))\d{3}\k<separator>\d{4})?" +
                       "((?<=\d)\s|(?<=^)|(?=$))" +
                       "(?<extension>x\d{4})?(?<=.)$");
```

- `^` start of string
- `(?<number>` start named group number
- `\d{3}` match 3 digits
- `(?<separator>` start named group separator
- `([\s-]|)` match space, `-` or empty string
- `)` close group seperator
- `\d{3}` match 3 digits
- `\k<separator>` match previous separator
- `\d{4}` match 4 digits
- `)` close group number
- `?` previous match is optional
- `((?<=d)\s|(<=^)|(?=$))` previous char is a digit and match space, or match zero length if at start or end of string
- `(?<extension>)` start named group extension
- `x\d{4}` match `x` followed by 4 digits.
- `)` close group extension
- `?` extension group is optional
- `(?<=.)` zero length match that insures string isn't empty
- `$` match end of string